How to dynamically update Leaflet markers with custom icons based on slider input?
I am working on a Shiny app where I want to display a Leaflet map with markers that have custom icons. The icons should change based on a year selected using a slider input. Specifically, markers should use a normalIcon if the selected year is within a certain range, and a crosshatchedIcon otherwise.
This is a simplified version of my code
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
normalIcon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0nMjAnIGhlaWdodD0nMjAnIHhtbG5zPSciaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9JzEwJyBjeT0nMTAnIHI9JzEwJyBmaWxsPSdibHVlJyAvPjwvc3ZnPg==",
  iconWidth = 20,
  iconHeight = 20
)

crosshatchedIcon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0nMjAnIGhlaWdodD0nMjAnIHhtbG5zPSciaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9JzEwJyBjeT0nMTAnIHI9JzEwJyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgLz48bGluZSB4MT0nMCcgeTE9JzAnIHgyPScyMCcgeTI9JzIwJyBzdHJva2U9J3doaXRlJyBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9JzInIC8+PGxpbmUgeDE9JzIwJyB5MT0nMCcgeDI9JzAnIHkyPScyMCcgc3Ryb2tlPSd3aGl0ZScgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPScyJyAvPjwvc3ZnPg==",
  iconWidth = 20,
  iconHeight = 20
)

# Sample data for locations
latlong_data <- data.frame(
  Latitude = c(9.26450, 9.36634, 9.40091, 9.32560, 9.15926, 9.32578),
  Longitude = c(41.44080, 41.77454, 41.41324, 41.16377, 42.18467, 42.28893),
  startyear = c(2008, 2004, 2008, 2008, 2018, 2021),
  endyear = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2012, 2023, 2023)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("year", "Year", min = 2000, max = 2025, value = 2015, step = 1, sep = ""),
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        data = latlong_data,
        lng = ~Longitude,
        lat = ~Latitude,
        icon = normalIcon
      )
  })

  observe({
    selected_year <- input$year
    icons <- ifelse(latlong_data$startyear <= selected_year & latlong_data$endyear >= selected_year, normalIcon, crosshatchedIcon)
    
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(
        data = latlong_data,
        lng = ~Longitude,
        lat = ~Latitude,
        icon = icons
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The markers on the map do not update as expected when the slider value changes. Instead, they always display the same icon regardless of the slider input. The markers should use normalIcon if the selected year falls within the startyear and endyear range and crosshatchedIcon if the selected year is outside the startyear and endyear range.

This question is similar to: Is there a way in R leaflet to assign different icons to certain locations?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
